# Unable to get activity facebook share button (SDK 4.0)

Tags: android, facebook, listview, adapter, share-button

I have a `ListView` inside each item I have a  facebook share button

```
<com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
```

But when I click on the button 
MediaAdapter.java inside `public View getView(final int  position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent)`

```
holder.button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setTag(holder);        
        Drawable mDrawable =  holder.imageview.getDrawable();
        Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                        .setBitmap(image)
                        //.setCaption("Give me my codez or I will ... you know, do that thing you don't like!")
                         .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                         .addPhoto(photo)
                         .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, null);  

    }   

});
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: cast to ShareButton not Button in holder.button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);

Comment: thank you   but the problem still exists after the cast  "  holder.button = (ShareButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);  "